# Common image folders for 2 different sites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I'm about to start developing a new website that will use the same database and also the same images. They will both be hosted in the same managed dedicated server. I really don't want to duplicate the images folder, and also don't want to use absolute urls: `<img src="http://www.site1.com/images/img.png" ... />`

What would be the best solution to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add another `Alias` entry to each virtual hosts configuration. That way you can create a "virtual 'images' folder" in both pages which is internally resolved to the same folder in the physical file system:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    [...]
    Alias /images /path/to/physical/images/folder
    <Directory /path/to/physical/images/folder>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        [...]
    </Directory
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    [...]
    Alias /images /path/to/physical/images/folder
    <Directory /path/to/physical/images/folder>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        [...]
    </Directory
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you can use images like `<img src="/images/img.png">` in both sites and the requests will be routed to the same physical folder.

Obviously there are other solutions, using the loopback interface to internally mount the images folder to a second location in the file system or using symlinks. But the above is the most elegant in my eyes...

Comment: Thanks arkascha for your reply.
The problem is that I'm hosted by 1and1 and have a managed dedicated server, so I don't think I will be able to edit virtual hosts configuration... Or can this be done using .htaccess?

Comment: OK, I understood before that you have a real control over the system. But then how can you serve two different domains and still share part of the file system between them? Is that possible at all? I would expect them to be strictly separated?

Comment: for the moment, nothing is shared between the different domains, the only thing I need to share is the "images" folder.
And regarding the database, I know i can use the same username and code since it's in the same server :)

Comment: So, _can_  you access the same folder in a file system from two separate domains? You did not answer that... Little sense in thinking about the http server configuration if the base is not available. If not you could think about using apache's proxy module inside a rewrite rule to fetch the images from on "main" domain in background, but that is ugly and slow.

Comment: Hi, yes, I can access the same folder from 2 separate domains, I haven't tried it but i guess it's possible...
the content of "site1" is in a folder in "htdocs":
`htdocs
     |---site1
     |---site2`
all main content is in site1, is it possible to make a rewrite rule for site2 for `/images/img.png` to actually display pictures from `../site1/images/img.png` ?

Comment: As said: the only thing that comes into mind here is the combination of proxy module and rewrite rules, _if the proxy module is available at all in such an environment_. And as said: ugly and slow. Did you ask your support for a solution for this? I mean you pay for it...

Comment: OK thanks! I'll get in touch soon with the support regarding this matter and hope to come up with a nice and beautiful solution :)